# Change the config settings per column in a Grafana table

Tags: grafana

I have a table in Grafana that has several columns and uses the gauge display mode.  Setting the min/max values for these columns is troublesome.  If the column is a percentage value the max is always known so can be hard coded as 100 or 1.  But for example a column displaying database sizes the max is not known and will change.

I am running Grafana 8.1.2 so tried the new 'config from query results' transform for the first time.  This works fine to alter the values of a single column but not for more than one.

[Grafana Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcAef.png)

As you can see in the attached picture I have set the max for the database size using the new transform but I also need to be able to set the max for the log size column too.

The dashboard has 2 queries in it, both for MSSQLServer. Query A returns the results in a table format and Query B returns the config settings: [query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13lS1.png)

I've then got the transform set up as follows: [transform set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zS321.png)

Is there a way to set the min\max settings for multiple columns using this new transform that I'm missing or some other technique to do it. Unfortunately (for me) Grafana seems to favour time series data so isn't as configurable for table data.

Comment: You can apply a transformation several times. Just add one more 'config from query results' and make it for the `log size` column.

Comment: I tried that. I split the configuration query in two. So had a query B and C.  But when adding a second 'config from query results' transform it didn't have any queries available in the config query drop down